# Play mediaelement full screen in pivot control windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to play my MediaElement fullscreen when the page-orientation changes in my Windows Phone application. I also apply when the page orientation repeat then player work properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do any changes in your page in this event :

```
        void MainPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft || e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)
        {

        mediaPlayer.Height = Double.NaN;
        mediaPlayer.Width = Double.NaN;

        mediaPlayer.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        mediaPlayer.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

        SystemTray.IsVisible = false;

        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: it not working properly because i want to play media element full screen in pivot application. and in above code pivot title and pivot item header a not hide and player not play in full screen. please given me another solution. Thanx

Comment: hide the panorama when you want to play media element

Comment: but when i hide panorama all the panorama item are hide

Comment: yes and this is the meaning of full screen so you need to view it outside panaorama in this case

Comment: create another instance of media elemnt at run time and make it full screen after hiding panorama

Comment: MediaElement media = new MediaElement();
            media.Height = Double.NaN;
            media.Width = Double.NaN;
            media.Source = new Uri("my url", UriKind.Absolute);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(media);
            media.Play();